# Execution time for each forked process perl

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork, perl-module

I am executing a script and have forked it to run parallel.

I notice that some of the processes take more time to execute and want to keep a track of each process when it started and ended.

Right now, I am printing the time to the terminal while executing but its not easy to determine which process is taking time to execute.

Is there a way to track it while using Perl Parallel:ForkManager?

Comment: I imagine you could use a module like [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::HiRes) to create hash(es) of start/stop times for each thread, then take the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear whether you are looking for real-time feedback on the processes that are running or whether you are just looking to understand if one child took longer at the end. Assuming you just want to know a final result, the following will suffice:

Use Benchmark, and the run_on_finish callback of Parallel::ForkManager. Something like this may work for you. We store the start time of the forked process when we fork it. When the child exits, Parallel::ForkManager will call the run_on_finish callback with the pid that exited. You can then store the end time of the child and then calculate the differences with Benchmark.

```
use Benchmark;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $max_forks = 5;

my $mgr = Parallel::ForkManager->new( $max_forks );

my %times;
$mgr->run_on_finish(sub {
    my $pid = shift;
    $times{$pid}->[1] = Benchmark->new; # end time mark
});

for ( 1 .. $max_forks+1 ) {  # N+1 to show that wait time isn't included.
    if (my $pid = $mgr->start) {  # Parent
        $times{$pid} = [Benchmark->new, undef]; #start time
        next;
    }

    srand(time^$$); # don't do this in real-world, perldoc srand
    my $sleep = int(rand(9));
    say "$$ sleeping $sleep";
    sleep ($sleep);
    $mgr->finish;
}

$mgr->wait_all_children;

foreach my $pid (keys %times) {
    say "Pid: $pid, ProcessTime: ", timestr(timediff($times{$pid}->[1], $times{$pid}->[0]));
}
```

Please refer to Benchmark perldocs for details on the output you can calculate and further functions.

- Mike